# Embedding matplotlib toolbar in pyqt?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm attempting to embed a matplotlib figure within a PyQt user interface (a QDialog, specifically). I can successfully embed my figure using the FigureCanvasQTAgg backend, but I really need the matplotlib toolbar to embed as well. Most examples I see use these import lines:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
```

The first works fine, but I ran into an import error with the second. After some googling, I discovered that the NavigationToolbar2QTAgg backend has deprecated in the most recent versions of matplotlib, and I haven't been able to find the updated alternative. Any help would be much appreciated even if it's just a point in the right direction.

I'm running PyQt4 and the most recent version of matplotlib.

Comment: Looking at the current version at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py I see it does `from .backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT`.  You could try that (i.e., `from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT`).

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4_wtoolbar.html for a qt embedding example with the tool bar.